# Removing a N.A value in a data frame

Tags: r

i am a begginer in R, im working with a csv archive named rere.csv so trying to get the mean of quality column with this code:

```
x<-read.csv("rere.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

mean(x$quality)
```

But i get this:

> Warning message: In mean.default(x$quality) :   argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA

```
quality
5
6
2
2
4
9
41
1
5
N.A
2
23
2
9
5
62
2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
x<-read.csv("rere.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", na.strings = "N.A")

mean(x$quality, na.rm = TRUE)
```

You can read the help page `?read.csv` for more info on the arguments, including `na.strings`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data has `N.A` entries for missing values. By default, R expects `NA`, but you can tell `read.csv` that `N.A` is missing data

```
x <- read.csv("rere.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", na.strings = "N.A")
```

This will allow R to read the column in as a numeric with missing values rather than a factor (categorical) variable. To get a mean of the non-missing values only, you'll have to tell `mean` to leave out the NA's.

```
mean(x$quality, na.rm = TRUE)
```